# How to properly change a name of Entity with Codegen: Class Definition?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI (but I think that UI Kit would not make a difference here) code in ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @FetchRequest(
            entity: EntityName.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var entityName: FetchedResults<EntityName>

    var body: some View {

        Text("test")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I have also created an Entity with a name: **EntityName**, class: EntityName, Module: Current Product Module, Codegen: Class Definition.

Now let's say I need to change my Entity name to **NewEntityName**. I will:

1. Change every occurrence of EntityName in ContentView to NewEntityName
2. Go to ProjectName.xcdatamodeld and Show Data Model Inspector
3. Change Name to NewEntityName
4. Change Class to NewEntityName
5. Choose Product -> Clean Build Folder
6. Choose Product -> Build
7. Resume Preview for ContentView

After all those steps I am getting an error:

> Use of undeclared type 'NewEntityName'

on line:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: NewEntityName.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var entityName: FetchedResults<NewEntityName>
```

Is it some bug in Xcode? Or am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with following (tested as worked with Xcode 11.2)

1. Open Find Navigator
2. Find 'OldEntityName'
3. Replace all with 'NewEntitityName'; Save all.
4. Clean-Build >> Success
5. Refresh Preview >> Fail
6. Restart Xcode
7. Clean-Build
8. Refresh Preview >> Success

Comment: Thanks. It worked after: Restart >> Clean Build Folder >> Build >> Preview